QGIS field calculator encoding issue
I have two shapefiles (UTF-8), and I want to use the field calculator to transfer attributes between features.
But it keeps messing up my texts because of encoding issues.
What is the preferred encoding for using the field calculator properly?


Which QGIS version are you running exactly and on which Operative System exactly?
Please share sample layers and the exact expression used in order to replicate the issue.

Any expression that copies values containing accents (ó, í, á, etc). Windows, QGIS 3.28 Firenze.

QGIS 3.28 is a 2 year old version. Please try if the issue occurs also running a currently supported QGIS version like QGIS LTR >= 3.34.13 or QGIS >= 3.40.1. If yes, please provide sample layers in order to replicate the issue..
I cannot replicate the issue just using QGIS 3.34.14 on Windows 10 and two ESRI Shapefile layers with text fields UTF-8 encoded containing accented letters.

Bay the way, I cannot replicate the issue even using QGIS 3.28.15 or QGIS 3.28.2 on Windows 10.

Thank you for the feedback.... Maybe it's an issue generating the layers with Global Mapper then. I'll investigate further. Unfortunately I can't share these layers as they contain sensible data.

I guess the ESRI Shapefile layer are not actually UTF-8 encoded or the .cpg sidecar file is missing or contains incorrect or not recognized codec info. What Global Mapper version are you using exactly? It looks like Global Mapper should be able to export an ESRI Shapefile layer UTF-8 encoded since version 15.2 according to https://www.bluemarblegeo.com/knowledgebase/global-mapper-24/Formats/Shapefile.htm
